# Android Studio - This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: android, android-studio, qemu

I've installed Android Studio to run a React Native application on an android emulator.

I've followed the instructions from the [react native website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) under Windows / Android.
Now when I try to run the simulator I'm getting the error below. I've searched for the error but no useful results found.

I've reinstalled Android Studio but to no success. Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled windows, did the trick, now works. No idea what caused that in the first place. If it's some corrupted file somewhere no chance to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting same error while launching Android Emulator.
My c drive Users folder was hidden and Ready Only. I unchecked both Read Only and Hidden chekboxes.
Then it started working for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Supriya Bhosale . I still couldn't find the issue so I did a clean Windows reinstall which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Supriya Bhosale's answer to unhide the folder - specifically the Android/Sdk folder.

I moved my Android/Sdk to D drive because of C space constraint. In my Windows 10 desktop it was working even with the Android\Sdk folder hidden. But not in Windows 11. So unhiding it fixed this error for me on Windows 11 using Dolphin version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the features, I found that my emulator had an update (I think it was displaying this because there were missing files but I don't know for sure).

## To fix this:

#### 1. navigate to Android SDK settings

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK

#### 2. Uninstall SDK platforms (Optional)

Under the SDK Platforms tab uncheck the Images which you are trying to use and click apply.

I did this before I updated my emulator, I don't know if this contributed to fixing my problem but I have not opened android studio for about a year so I figured reinstalling the SDK platforms wouldn't do any harm.

#### 3. Update (or reinstall) the Emulator

In the SDK Tools tab find Android Emulator, if there is a dash in the box that should be checked, it means that there is an update available. Click it until it is checked and click apply to begin the update.

If the box is already checked, you could try unchecking and applying to uninstall and then checking it and applying again to reinstall it to see if that works.

This is my first ever stack overflow post, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after following the react native tutorial for windows. I'm using windows 11 and I managed to solve this problem by uninstalling android studio cleanly and reinstalling it. it worked for me.